# Offroad experience in Germany

Tags: germany, recommendations, off-road

I'm looking for a offroad park in Germany, where I can rent an offroad vehicle (but not an ATV) and have some fun for 2-3 days. The best case would be such a place in Hesse or Rhineland-Palatinate, but the rest of Germany is still OK.
 As I have almost no experience, it would be great if there is a trail for beginners. Any recommendations?

Comment: Not sure if "recommendations" is the best way to put it, shopping recommendations are somewhat off-topic. Consider instead asking for a list of places in provinces X, Y, and Z, or in a radius of W km around city N. You probably wouldn't want to go to Rostock if you live in Munich, for example.

Comment: I'm with @mindcorrosive on this one.  But I think what you're looking for is http://www.wikiloc.com/trails/atv/germany

Comment: @mindcorrosive if the best offer is in Berlin, we're gonna go there, the distance doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Karlson No, I'm not looking for atv-trails. With offroad vehicles I mean something like Jeep Wrangler or Mercedes G-Class

Comment: http://www.toytowngermany.com/lofi/index.php/t43014.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: I am a bit surprised that offroad parks here are relatively scarce, but on the other hand Germany is very densely populated with not so much ample room for activities. There you go:

Hessen, Knüllwald

http://www.offroadpark-knuellwald.de/index.php

Berlin, Jänschwalde

http://www.einmalige-erlebnisse.de/products/Motorpower/Hummer-H1-offroad-selber-fahren/30-Min-Hummer-H1-offroad-selber-fahren-in-Jaenschwalde.html

Mecklenburg-Vorpommern, Karenz

http://www.ofck.de/

Bavaria, Langenaltheim:

http://www.offroadpark-langenaltheim.de

Saxony-Anhalt, Wurzelsepp

http://www.wurzelsepp-peckfitz.de/gelaende.htm

Lower Saxony, Fürstenforest

http://www.furstenforest.de/

Lower Saxony, near Hessen, Stadtoldendorf

http://www.fpmammut.de/

Mecklenburg-Vorpommen, Steinhagen

http://www.msc-nordvorpommern.de/

Answer (score 4):

OK, no ATVs. How about the other side of the spectrum, tanks?

A place where you can drive [Panzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panzer) has been in the news a couple of times. It is close to Berlin. I believe it must be [Panzerkutscher](http://www.panzerkutscher.de/en/index.htm). They have a big terrain, some old cars (to crush), and various tanks at the disposal of any paying customer [above the age of 16 years](http://www.panzerkutscher.de/panzer_fahren.htm). You can drive, take repair courses, etc.